Google Vault API Usage
We are facing some issues with the Google Vault API. When retrieving data using the Vault API in my Python automation, we only receive 28 matters. we tried the same request with Postman and also received only 28 matters. Could you please guide us on where the issues might be? We will share the Postman and Python outputs below for your review
enter image description here
Google Vault API details :  user_info = service.users().get(userKey=user_id).execute()
service.matters().get(matterId=matter_id, view='FULL').execute()
We are using the above to fetch the vault user report from Google vault, we would need confirmation whether this API is correct or not?
If the above is correct, we are getting the limited number of users, please see output.
